# Setting docker ip and port prevents me from using docker ps -a

Tags: docker

I start docker on a specified ip and port like so:

```
sudo docker -H 192.168.1.164:4243 -d
```

I can then make API calls to get a list of containers via the API:

```
curl -XGET http://192.168.1.164:4243/containers/json?all=1
```

The command above successfully return the list of containers.

But, when I run `docker ps -a`  I get the following error:

```
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is 'docker -d' running on this host?
```

I don't see how I can set the ip and port in the `docker ps` command. Is there a way around this? How can I start docker at a specific ip and port *and* still use the `docker ps` command to list my containers?

Update:

I tried using the -H flag:

`docker -H tcp://192.168.1.164:4243 ps`  this command hangs. I think it's because -H is only used when starting docker and binding it to an ip and port.

OS:  Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Untested, but the [docs](http://docs.docker.io/reference/commandline/cli/#daemon) suggest using the `-H` option on your client command or setting `DOCKER_HOST`:

```
$ docker -H tcp://192.168.1.164:4243 ps
```

Or :

```
$ export DOCKER_HOST="tcp://192.168.1.164:4243"
# Then:
$ docker ps
```

EDIT:

I fired up a fresh vagrant 12.04 machine, installed docker, ran a few sample containers against the default configuration, then ran:

```
sudo service docker stop
sudo docker -H 10.0.2.15:4243 -d &
sudo docker -H 10.0.2.15:4243 ps -a
```

Output from the `docker ps` (including from backgrounded daemon):

```
2014/05/22 22:42:16 GET /v1.11/containers/json?all=1
[92cd0057] +job containers()
[92cd0057] -job containers() = OK (0)
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS                     PORTS               NAMES
dcd486abb7b4        ubuntu:14.04        ls                  2 minutes ago       Exited (0) 2 minutes ago                       furious_kowalevski    
d9d31c5e6baa        ubuntu:14.04        /bin/bash           2 minutes ago       Exited (0) 2 minutes ago                       backstabbing_yonath   
9b77e6035ca2        ubuntu:14.04        /bin/bash           2 minutes ago       Exited (0) 2 minutes ago                       clever_newton
```

So, in general, it works.  What's particular about your environment, it's hard to say.

Comment: Thanks for bringing that up. I should have mentioned that I tried the -H flag.  The -H flag binds the daemon to an ip and port. Not really what I wanted. I'll update my question.

Comment: `-H` also works for the Docker client, I'm 100% sure of that. If you started your daemon (`-d`) with a `-H something` option, you should also use the same option to make the client communicate with the daemon.

Comment: @oeuftete I wasn't passing the -H arguments correctly.  Thanks for the answer.